# Can you use this in combination with is?

Tags: typescript

Assuming the following definition of `x` and `y` in a `Pointer` class:

```
x: number | undefined = undefined;
y: number | undefined = undefined;
```

Is there any way to give the class a function like this:

```
public isPointerReady(): this.x is number && this.y is number {
  return this.x !== undefined && this.y !== undefined;
}
```

so in client code I could do something like this:

```
if (pointer.isPointerReady()) { 
  // can safely access pointer.x and pointer.y and use them as numbers
}
```

Comment: You can write `this is {x: number; y: number}` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WkaY1N). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I do think you can give it a function like this. However the return type would be `this is Pointer` assuming your class is called `Pointer`. `this is Pointer` indicates that if the function returns true, then the current object (i.e., `this`) is of type `Pointer`, meaning both x and y are numbers.

Comment: Did you try it? Yes, you can use `this` in a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates): https://tsplay.dev/Wv1D3m. But no you can't access properties on `this`, _"`parameterName` must be the name of a parameter from the current function signature"_ not an arbitrary expression (even using the type `this["propName"]` wouldn't help).

Comment: @jcalz Ah perfect I did not know that was possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't combine [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) like `(x is T) && (y is U)`.  There's an open feature request for it at [microsoft/TypeScript#26916](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26916).  You also can't directly guard *properties* in type predicates like `x.prop is T`.  There's an open feature request for that also at [microsoft/TypeScript#11117](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11117).  Until and unless these are implemented, you'll need to write your type guard method differently:

```
public isPointerReady(): this is { x: number, y: number } {
    return this.x !== undefined && this.y !== undefined;
}
```

Here we are guarding `this` directly instead of `this.x` and `this.y`, but it has the same effect as what you were looking for:

```
const pointer = new Pointer();
pointer.x.toFixed(); // error! 'pointer.x' is possibly 'undefined'
pointer.y.toFixed(); // error! 'pointer.y' is possibly 'undefined'
if (pointer.isPointerReady()) {
    pointer.x.toFixed(); // okay
    pointer.y.toFixed(); // okay
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKD2BLAdgFwKYCdoG8BQ0h0AHgFzTICuAtgEZbQA+0lyAJugGYrpvQC8Ldlx5sA3ASIBPclToNmrDt2S8BQ5aIlFoAL3IRUmFAHN1AInOTCAB0q0QiYNEQQEKDJgBK6MGykAFACU5KgAFq4uMDgksjT0mAA00DIU8QwAvrjWOtCY6KiUmMjQ4a4AdMTQAIT8gkoiqnwAZM2lERDlUjV1Go282kQZeMN4wPDIhtA2SGgMgqoA7nCznsESMx5YleWo8ABiiMS869AA9GfQWJjwmNXQAOSbc5iVD1HT8FCIDt0PDSpeA88M9PF1dgcjicgmJzpdrrd7k9VtspO9IjNvr9HgDRMDEJxoAFQdtXO4Xj4-IEgkFsjoSa9iBDDsc2KcLtB4ABrMBSHIM8F7FnQ2Ec7m8kZ4PBAA)